# Accessing multiple paths using the JSON baseQuery

Tags: json

We are using Unily as our intranet platform and it uses JSON to configure search data sources such as SharePoint. How can I get the configuration to look at more than one SharePoint site as a source?

Here is the base code:

```
{
    "baseQuery": "path:https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ImportantFolder",
    "entityTypes": [
        "list",
        "driveItem"
    ],
    "fieldsToRetrieve": [
        "name",
        "displayName",
        "webUrl",
        "lastModifiedDateTime",
        "lastModifiedBy",
        "parentReference"
    ],
    "tokenBasedPaging": false
}
```

What is the syntax for searching?:
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ImportantFolder
OR
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/AnotherImportantFolder
OR
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/StillAnotherFolder

I tried:

```
"baseQuery": [
"path:https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ImportantFolder",
"path:https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/AnotherImportantFolder"
],
```

I hoped it would look in both paths and return anything it found for the search term, but it didn't return anything. And I verified the search term was returned with just the first path configured and the search term exists in both paths.